# How can I return a Task<List<Model>> from dapper for "Select * from table" without having to query the resulting ids from the first query again?

Tags: c#, dapper, blazor-server-side

I am working on a blazor server side project.
I wrote a repository pattern class for my queries and had some troubles with the function `Task<List<Model>> GetAllModelsAsync()`. I want it to return a task so I can await its result within my partial components class to allow more responsive rendering.

I got it working using the following code:

```cs
public Task<List<Model>> GetAllModelsAsync()
        {
            List<Model> modelList = new();
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM model";
            var query = DbConnection.QueryAsync<Model>(sql).Result;
            
            var result = query.ToList();
            foreach (var model in result) modelList.Add(GetModelAsync(int.Parse($"{model.Id}")).Result);

            return Task.FromResult(modelList);
        }
```

Even though it is working it doesn't feel like being the best version
since I have read that the following syntax should be working:

```cs
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...)) 
{ 
  var authors = connection.Query<Author>(
    "Select * From Author").ToList(); 
}
```

I noticed that the following syntax is working as well:

```cs
var query = (await DbConnection.QueryAsync<Model>(sql)).ToList();
```

Though I have to change my method to async now.

I tried to define a task for it but was not able to get it working.

```cs
var sql = "SELECT * FROM model";
var task = new Task<List<Model>>(async () =>
{
  (await DbConnection.QueryAsync<Model>(sql)).ToList();
});

return task
```

Now I get `return type of an 'async' anonymous function must be a 'void', 'Task', 'Task<T>', a task-like type, 'IAsyncEnumerable<T>', or 'lAsyncEnumerator<T>'`

Most of the answers to the error state I have to return some type of Task<..> but I actually do return it.

I am not even sure if this wouldn't destroy my intended logic.
thanks in advance! Regarding perfomance I am not even sure if a have any benefit from having to run GetSkill so often for my first solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I've been using Dapper.  Works great:

1. Make your Dapper method `async`.
2. Make the method or event that CALLS your method an `async Task` as well, so you can `await` the Task.
3. To return a list, do `return (await blah blah blah).ToList();`
4. Use the `Async` versions of all SQL calls.

Something seems a little off with your foreach loop.  Would you mind explaining what you're trying to achieve with it?  It seems like your first query should return all the models you need.

Example:

```
public async Task<List<ImageChoiceQuestion>> GetImageChoiceQuestionsByCreator(string AddedByUserId)
{
    string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString));
    return (await connection.QueryAsync<ImageChoiceQuestion>(QImage.GetImageChoiceQuestionsByCreator, new { AddedByUserId })).ToList();
}
```

`QImage.GetImageChoiceQuestionsByCreator` is just a query string.

Comment: ok thanks I will try this right away. My for each is just read out all id's from first query , query the id and add it to the result.  Feels a little weird to me as well.

Comment: When you do that query, all of the rows' contents are already there in your first result set.  I recommend doing `var results = (await blah blah blah).ToList(); return results;`  That way if you set a breakpoint after your Dapper query, you can hover over `results` to get a popup showing the complete list.

Comment: it works for great this example but when I try to use it for my other functions I get `Exit code is 134 (Unhandled exception. Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (BeginExecuteNonQuery requires an ... `because I use the `GetSillAsync` within my `UpdateSkillAsync` and it seems he doesn't want me to open up a new connection. I think QueryMultiple is not working here since I open it up in the different function.

Comment: I create a new `using connection` in each method.  I'll edit my answer to give an example from my code.

Comment: I used [this pattern from the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218847/how-do-i-handle-database-connections-with-dapper-in-net) to strip the connection stuff away from my code. I actually just noticed that I shouldn't use Task.FromResult [at all](https://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/should-i-await-on-task-fromresult-method-calls) and this was causing some troubles here. I just needed to query in my update first so I see whether it is already exists so I can't add data again and again.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward answer I think should be:

```
public async Task<List<Model>> GetAllModelsAsync()
    {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM model";
        var result = (await DbConnection.QueryAsync<Model>(sql))).ToList();
        
        return result;
    }
```

I can't say I've got much Dapper experience, but with your initial implementation you were using:

1. .Result -> .Result means that you're going to block and wait for the task to complete to get the result of the query so that it can be used immediately. Using the await keyword instead (which means one has to also add the `async` keyword to the method definition) means that while whatever async method you're awaiting is executing, you won't block the thread and the currently executing thread can be used for something else in the meantime until the result is ready. I'd recommend [Steven Cleary's blog posts](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) about async await as a good reference.
2. You don't need the foreach loop I think. You're getting all the models with the first call, so you shouldn't need to requery them on a per Id basis?

You'll then call this method like

```
var allModels = await GetAllModelsAsync();
```

Comment: I really don't see why this person would be doing any kind of `.Select()` or other Linq stuff at all.  They should be able to just run the query and return the results.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Yeah I think that's my misunderstanding/lack of knowledge of how dapper works as I mentioned in the answer. I'll remove that bit

Comment: I've actually ONLY ever used Dapper, so I don't know the difference any more than you do.  I think  you can remove `List<Model> modelList = new();`

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 yeah you're right thanks :)

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 an explanation just because: with entity framework, there isn't auto entity mapping, and you don't supply a query with actual sql strings (usually). So as part of the query you supply a .Select function which limits the fields that are selected in the query (the select x,y,z part of the query) and then that can be manaully mapped to an object like I explained previously (the now removed bit)

Comment: Ah yes, I remember that now.  I was pretty excited by EF when I started with Blazor.  I studied a video tutorial series by IAmTimCorey at that time, and he recommended Dapper.  I haven't really seen the need to go back, though I've seen there have been great improvements lately, and more to come in .net 6.