# How to point all connection string in generated strongly typed datasets to use appsettings default connectionstring in ASP.NET Core Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

How can I point all generated dataset schema connection string to use `appsettings` default connection string in ASP.NET Core Razor pages?

Note: this works perfectly in ASP.NET Webforms and ASP.NET MVC, but not in ASP.NET Core with Razor pages.

Generated code from dataset Xsd Schema:

```
private void InitConnection()
{
    this._connection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
    this._connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=mylocaldb;Integrated Security=True";
}
```

I want the connection string to point to the `appsettings.json` default connection.

Thanks

Please click the link to view the Image: How can I override the InitConnection() at runtime. Note: this is actually a generated code by visual studio and everytime I update the dataset it will automatically reset back to default so I can't use change the code.

[Please click to view the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDJrr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Below code in dotnet core should be same as yours.

```
services.AddScoped<IDbConnection, SqlConnection>(serviceProvider => {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = 
             Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connectionstring");
    return conn;
});
```

*For more details, you can refer below sample code:*

[How do I handle Database Connections with Dapper in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403685/7687666)

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. The challenge I have here is the xsd codes are generated codes (Datasets.Designer.cs) If I change the InitConnection() to point to the appSettings, Everytime I add/Update the Dataset schema (Xsd), it will revert back to default connectionstring This._connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=mylocaldb;Integrated Security=True";

Comment: I have updated the question thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:  (The simple way)**

You could use`IConfiguration` interface. In the bellow code, I inject the`IConfiguration` interface to your code and use it.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private  IConfiguration _configuration { get;}
    
   public MyClass(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
       _configuration = configuration;
   }

   private void InitConnection()
   {
       this._connection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
       this._connection.ConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
   }
}
```

and here is the`appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=mylocaldb;Integrated Security=True"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**Solution 2: (The best way)**

Add a service in your `startup.cs` file and inject the service to your classes.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. The challenge I have here is the xsd codes are generated codes (Datasets.Designer.cs) If I change the InitConnection() to point to the appSettings, Everytime I add/Update the Dataset schema (Xsd), it will revert back to default connectionstring This._connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=mylocaldb;Integrated Security=True";

Comment: I have added image to the question thanks