# No member matching data has been found - Registering Dictionary in Unity Container

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I'm attempting to be able to use multiple db connections in different repositories and am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403685/4107391).

I am on .NET Framework 4.8 so things are a little different but everything has been mostly the same. The issue I'm running into is when I try to create a new dictionary in `UnityConfig.cs`.

The following code is throwing the error, specifically on the line where I'm attempting to register the dictionary.

```
var connectionDict = new Dictionary<DatabaseConnectionName, string>
{
    { DatabaseConnectionName.Connection1, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection1"].ConnectionString },
    { DatabaseConnectionName.Connection2, Configurationmanager.ConnectionStrings["Connection2"].ConnectionString }
};

container.RegisterType<IDictionary<DatabaseConnectionName, string>>(new InjectionConstructor(connectionDict));
container.RegisterType<IDbConnectionFactory, DapperDbConnectionFactory>();
```

> ERROR: System.ArgumentException: No member matching data has been found.

I'm assuming it's a silly mistake but I just can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you just have to post to SO to solve your own problems lol.

I changed

```
container.RegisterType<IDictionary<DatabaseConnectionName, string>>(new InjectionConstructor(connectionDict));
```

to

```
container.RegisterType<IDictionary<DatabaseConnectionName, string>, Dictionary<DatabaseConnectionName, string>>(new InjectionConstructor(connectionDict));
```

and everything is working as expected now.