# Using closes sql connection brought over by a function

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [in a “using” block is a SqlConnection closed on return or exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717789/in-a-using-block-is-a-sqlconnection-closed-on-return-or-exception)

Would this `using` close this `_connection`?

```
using(SqlConnection _connection = Class1.GetSqlConnection())  
{   //code inside the connection
}

//connection should be closed/ended?
```

I'm just wondering because `GetSqlConnection()` is a static function of `Class1` and the whole connection might not be closed because it is calling outside class' static function instead of straight?

```
 using(SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)
 {   //code inside the connection
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it would close the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does.

Here is an alternative way to implement the `GetSqlFunction` method so that you have a more explicit behaviour:

```
public class Class1
{
    private static SqlConnection GetSqlConnection() { /* unchanged */ }

    public static void UseSqlConnection(Action<SqlConnection> action)
    {
        using (var connection = Class1.GetSqlConnection())
        {
            action(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call it like so:

```
Class1.UseSqlConnection(c =>
{
    /* use connection here */
});
```

You could then extend this method to use an existing connection or create a new one depending on the semantics you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

The `using` statement does not care how the variable gets its value, - be it from a static function, a member function, a `new` operator, or any other way. As soon as the closing brace of the `using` is reached, the `Dispose()` method on the variable will be called, closing the connection if it's an `IDbConnection` instance, or doing whatever else the `IDisposable` is to do upon disposing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by design.

A `using` block is used to handle disposing of, well, disposable objects when the block ends. To `Dispose()` an object means to release all of the resources for that object. For objects such as `SqlConnection`, this will close their connection.