# Closing database connections

Tags: .net, sql, database

To close my database I use this : SqlConnection.Close();
But my application is stuck in this method...

Each time I access the Database I do this :

```
string cmdSQL = "select min(shortAddress) from FreeShortAddress";

using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(cmdSQL))    
{
    cmd.Connection = (SqlCeConnection)this.SqlConnection;    
    var r = cmd.ExecuteScalar();    
}
```

Is it the right way ?How can you see which connection (on which table) is blocked ?

Thank you.

[Edit]Do you know a command to force closing all connections without being stuck ?

Comment: yes.   what i posted in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general pattern I use when opening and closing connections is like this: (taken from [an older answer of mine on a question about the using statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717789/in-a-using-block-is-a-sqlconnection-closed-on-return-or-exception/4717802#4717802).)  This patterns closes the connection automatically when it is supposed to be closed. (When exiting the using statement)

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{    
  int employeeID = findEmployeeID();    
  try    
  {

            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UpdateEmployeeTable", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmployeeID", employeeID));
            command.CommandTimeout = 5;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();    
   } 
   catch (Exception) 
   { 
      /*Handle error*/ 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this:

```
using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(cmdSQL))    
{
    cmd.Connection = (SqlCeConnection)this.SqlConnection;    
    var r = cmd.ExecuteScalar(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);    
}
```

Comment: Ok, but later in my code I do the same but I don't use ExecuteScalar. When I close the SqlCeCommand, does the connection close too ?

Comment: it works with all the Executes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior(v=vs.100).aspx   You do not need to close it later on if you are using with your executions

Answer (score 0):

This is really a way to go while closing connection, I really used it everywhere to avoid clutter the code by using try catch statement, BTW you can use yield keyword in your version.
but not with try catch.:)