# Making sure a connection is closed

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I wanted to ask what is the common way of using database connections and closing them.

This is my program, but I see in an exeption, the connection.Close() will not execute.

Should i use a try-catch for the whole block? because for some reason i see most people doesnt.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "procedure";

                command.Connection = connection;

                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                tmpParameter = DBUtils.createInSQLParam("@ImageID", SqlDbType.SmallInt, htmlImageId);
                command.Parameters.Add(tmpParameter);

                command.Connection.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    htmlImageDetails = GetHtmlImageDetailsFromReader(reader, true, out newId);

                    reader.Close();
                }

                connection.Close();

                return htmlImageDetails;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exception are you seeing?

Comment: This seems to answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4717802/978528.

Comment: The close is not needed when using "using" the connections/readers are automatically closed. .net uses connection pooling by default so a connection is not closed if you dispose it it is put in the pool for reuse (this improves the performance in most cases).

Comment: Within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned. So, maybe when you close() that is considered as modification of the object because close() is implicit after the closing } of the using block thus the error.

Comment: Just to clarify what @Petoj said the connection is not closed when you call `Close()` either, it just returns the connection to the pool till it times out and then closes for real. (unless you told it to not use connection pooling in the connection string when you created the connection)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to do it explicitly, because your `SqlConnection` instance will always be disposed (and then, connection closed) thanks to the `using` syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

> Should i use a try-catch for the whole block? because for some reason
>   i see most people doesnt.

No. Since you are using [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement, that translates into `try-finally` block, so even if an exception occurs it will ensure the disposal of object.

[using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even **if an
>   exception occurs** while you are calling methods on the object. **You
>   can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block
>   and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler.**

[`SqlConnection.Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ensures that the connection is closed.

> To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection
>   inside of a `using` block, ....... Doing so ensures that the connection
>   is automatically closed when the code exits the block.

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the connection with a `using` block, and this means that the compiler will make sure that `Dispose()` gets called on the connection, which will call `Close()`. So not to worry, you don't need to `Close()` the connection yourself, even in case of an `Exception`.