# How to populate list or array with values from access database

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to populate a group of labels in a C# windows form with some values that are in a certain attribute (PlayerName) in a database that I have in access.

Currently the only code I have is:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(CONNECTION STRING HERE);

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "SELECT PlayerName FROM [TotalPlayerName] WHERE Team = 1 AND SportID = " + Form1.IDNumber;
```

I need a list or array that holds these values so I can use them to populate the labels, but I am unaware of how to do this.

Comment: What is the type of `PlayerName` column?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The type in the column is a string

Comment: while reading the data fill the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`ExecuteReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to obtain a data reader and then loop through the rows of the result set like this:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();

using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

Before you do this, don't forget to open the connection like this:

```
connection.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things here..... for sake of best practice well its more standard practice... as I like to say!

Use USING as this cleans up after connection.. see here for great examples [in a "using" block is a SqlConnection closed on return or exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717789/in-a-using-block-is-a-sqlconnection-closed-on-return-or-exception)

```
using (OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
       int fCount = DbReader.FieldCount;
       while (DbReader.Read())
         {
              Label1 = DbReader.GetString(0);
              Label2 = DbReader.GetString(1);
              Label3 = DbReader.GetString(2);
              Label4 = DbReader.GetString(3);

              for (int i = 0; i < fCount; i++)
                {
                   String col = DbReader.GetString(i);
                    Console.Write(col + ":");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
        }
}
```

NB your SQL only return 1 field /String at the moment

Answer (score 0):

One option might be using `OleDbDataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable` those values that returns your query;

```
var dt = new DataTable();
using(var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
{
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

And since your query return one column, you can use [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable) to *that* datatable to get them as a `string` like;

```
List<string> list = dt.AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(r => r.Field<string>("PlayerName"))
                      .ToList();
```

You can read: [Queries in LINQ to DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415.aspx)

By the way, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically as I did for `OleDbDataAdapter` in my example.

Comment: If it is going to a List then I would skip the overhead and steps of a DataTable

Comment: @Frisbee Well, kind of agreed. Using `ExecuteReader` is somewhat better in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

while reading the data fill the list like

```
List<string> players = new List<string>();

OleDbDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
While(rdr.Read())
{
  players.Add(rdr["PlayerName"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `OleDbReader` object to read the response from the query. You will also need to create a List to store the data Something like this:

```
List<string> playerNameList = new List<string>(); 
using (OleDbReader r = command.ExecuteReader())
{
   while(reader.Read())
   {
     playerNameList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
   }
}
```