# ASP.net database code using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, ado.net

Please tell me the error in this code, the data is not stored in the table.

```
SqlConnection con;
SqlCommand com;

string constr = @"Data Source=SQL5004.myASP.NET;Initial Catalog=DB_9F2D70_arjunb98;User Id=DB_9F2D70_arjunb98_admin;Password=#;";

protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();

        com = new SqlCommand();
        com.CommandText = "insert into table values ('" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "', '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "','" + name.Text + "','" + mail.Text + "', '" + Address.Text + "', '" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "', '" + ph.Text + "','" + message.Text + "')";

        com.Connection = con;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        Page.GetType(),
            "MessageBox", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Sorry! the data is not Submitted, Please try again ')</script>");
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: 1.  SQL Injection vulnerability.  2.  You're swallowing the exception - do something with it so you know what the error actually was.  3.  I'm 99.9% sure that you have to specify the columns as well as the values - and even if you don't, it's best practice to do so - what happens if you add columns to the table later?   4.  `table` is a SQL reserved word - did you actually name your table "table"?

Comment: Total weird code ... in a single sentence

Comment: Which line of your code is specific for ASP.NET? We do not care what the code runs in - if it is not relevant to the question, REMOVE THE TAG.

Answer (score 0):

Aahhhhh. You have messed up your code. Also you have not shown your `aspx` so I am not much aware of the *parameters* you are using.

Also as suggested by **Tim** your code is prone to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). So its better to used [parameterized queries](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx)(*recommended in your case*)

So a simple reference with your code will be as below:-

On `ButtonClick` you may write something like below

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SQL5004.myASP.NET;Initial Catalog=DB_9F2D70_arjunb98;User Id=DB_9F2D70_arjunb98_admin;Password=#;"); // connection string described by you
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Person(Column1,Column2,Column3,....) values(@Column1, @Column2, @Column3,...)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1", TextBoxID.text); // it may be option as per your requirement(ex:- Dropdownlist)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column2", textbox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column3", textbox3.Text);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    {
        label.Text = "Error when saving on database";
        conn.Close();
    }

    // Empty your controls here
    Control1.text = "";
    Control2.text = "";
    Control3.text = "";
}
```

There are also many other links available for your requirement.

**http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx**

Hope that helps and clarifies your doubt too.

Happy learning :)

Comment: You can also use [`using` statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717789/in-a-using-block-is-a-sqlconnection-closed-on-return-or-exception)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @user3332694: if it helped you, kindly accept it for others too :)

Comment: Hello sir, thank u very much, your code works very fine.

Comment: @user3332694: if it worked, kindly tick the answer. So it can be helpful to others