# Login takes the first user only

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have an login which works, but i only can login with the first user in the table

Can anyone explain why?

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=user\SQLEXPRESS; User ID=user;password=password;Initial Catalog=login;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    try
    {
        if (sqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password";
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pwd.Password);
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());

        if (count == 1)
        {
            MainDashboard window = new MainDashboard();
            this.Close();
            window.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username or Password");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

my table name is tblUsers and i have 2 users but i can only succesfully login with the first user in my table

Comment: if (count == 1) should be if (count > 0)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2   Says following "[scalar method] Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored."... From same page, "Use the ExecuteScalar method to retrieve a single value (for example, an aggregate value) from a database."

Comment: Side note: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: That solved my issue @RuiJarimba

Comment: @AhmadTI you still have some issues in your code. Consider using an `using` statement with the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects - example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4717789/558486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2) executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

So instead of

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password";
```

Try

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password";
```

Explanation:

- Using `ExecuteScalar()` with `SELECT *` will return the value of the first column of the row (I suppose that in your case it's the ID/primary key of table `tbluser`?)
- Using `ExecuteScalar()` with `SELECT Count(*)` will return `1` if the username and password matches (assuming there are no username/password duplicates).